# What (filtered) (homotopy) (co) limits does $\pi_0:\mathbf{sSets}\to\mathbf{Sets}$ preserve?

Tags: category-theory, simplicial-stuff

Consider the functor $\pi_0:\mathbf{sSets}\to\mathbf{Sets}$.

- $\pi_0$ does not preserve arbitrary limits
- $\pi_0$ does not send homotopy limits to limits
- $\pi_0$ does preserve filtered colimits
- $\pi_0$ does preserve arbitrary colimits

> - Does $\pi_0$ send homotopy colimits to colimits? I think, this is true.
> - Does $\pi_0$ preserve filtered limits? If not, what is a counterexample?
> - Does $\pi_0$ send filtered homotopy limits to filtered limits? If not, what is a counterexample?

Comment: Can you answer these questions for $\mathsf{Top}$ instead of $\mathsf{sSet}$? The first one is really easy.

Comment: Thanks, @MartinBrandenburg, you are right, sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\pi_0 : \mathbf{sSet} \to \mathbf{Set}$ is a left adjoint (exercise), so it preserves all colimits. It's also a left Quillen functor, so it even preserves homotopy colimits. There's no reason to believe anything good happens with (homotopy) limits, filtered or not, but it is true that finite (homotopy) products are preserved.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What is the right adjoint of $\pi_0$?

Comment: That's an exercise for you! As a hint, I'll mention that it is a fully faithful functor $\mathbf{Set} \to \mathbf{sSet}$.

Comment: Ok, yes discrete, I see.